# Bitstring Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am not understanding how to apply n choose r and permutations to the following problem.

Given a bit string of length 8 that has exactly three 0's, what is the probability that the bit string will begin with a 0?

Given a bit string of length 8 that has begins with a 1, what is the probability that it contains exactly three 1's?

How many bit strings of length 8 contain an evan number of 1's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only considering the first -- you should be able to adapt the reasoning for the other two. You have $\binom{8}{3}$ bit strings containing 3 zeros. You have $\binom{7}{2}$ bit strings containing 3 zeros with the first bit being 0 (can you see why?). Therefore (if it looks mysterious, write it as a conditional probability: $\Pr[A\mid B] = \frac{\Pr[A\cap B]}{\Pr[B]}$), you have a probability $$
\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{8}{3}}
$$
to draw, conditioned on your bitstring having exactly 3 zeros, a bitstring whose first bit is 0 when sampling uniformly.

Comment: So for "Given a bit string of length 8 that has begins with a 1, what is the probability that it contains exactly three 1's?" would you reverse the numerator and denominator?

Comment: @user232729 You can rephrase the question as: "..what is the probability that in rest of the string (first bit excluded) there are two $1$'s?"

Comment: @user232729 if you did this, it would give a value greater than 1. You would divide the number of strings starting with 1 and having 3 1's in total $(\binom{7}{2}$, again) by the number of strings starting with 1 (there are $2^7$ of them). (here, probabilities and numbers are interchangeable, because they are exactly within a normalizing factor $2^8$ of each other, which disappears when doing the ratio of two probabilities)

Comment: I'm confused on the comment above, can you please explain further?

Comment: Also, How can I go about using permutations and combinations for "bit strings of length 8 contain an evan number of 1's"

Comment: @user232729: what part of the comment confuses you, so that I can elaborate?

Comment: @ClementC. are you suggesting that I subtract the above probability by 1, because it is asking the opposite?

Comment: No: read the above carefully, to see how to apply either (a) conditional probabilities; or (b) rephrasing as numbers (this is equivalent) to your problem. You want to know both the number of strings that satisfy (i) /and/ (ii), and the number of strings that satisfy (ii), and take the ratio: in your case, (i) will be "contains 3 1's" and (ii) will be "starts with a 1", for instance.